# Can't connect to WiFi via WiFi USB in rear panel, but can in front

Tags: fedora, wifi

I recently built a PC and I wanted to connect to WiFi by a USB dongle. WiFi is broadcasted via repeater. Host network is from my Android phone.
The problem is that I cannot connect to WiFi when dongle is put to rear USB ports (soldered to motherboard). It only asks me to put password without connecting finally, but connecting to the same network when dongle is in my PC case USB ports (that are connected to ports on MB) is possible. 
That is a bizzare thing to me, because I thought that rear and front USB ports are some kind of *logically the same* for the motherboard.
Funny thing that I can connect to host network (without repeater) in both cases.

Equipment:
*Motherboard*: ASRock X370M PRO4
*WiFi*: TP-Link TL-WN725N nano (R8188EU chip)
*System*: Fedora 31

Is that a problem with my motherboard and I need to get a new one or there is something that I don't know?

Thank you for help.

Comment: When you connect your dongle to the rear, is your repeater on the front-side of the PC, i.e. is your PC then between your repeater and the dongle? Have you tried a usb extension cable to let the dongle sticj-out a bit further?

Comment: Now it works. I didn't think about USB extension. Still strange, because whole PC is really close to repeater. 
Maybe I was too mean wehn buying a dongle and I should buy something more expensive with better antenna.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue for years. I even tried to put the wifi just behind the PC case.

Equipment:
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-78LMT-S2 
WiFi: TP-Link TL-WN725N nano 
System: Window 10

Answer (score 0):

Most PCs are made of metal. That shields-off radio waves. You do not need to be in a complete Faraday cage to have problematic WiFi connection.

Also, PCs tend to add noise to the radio waves. So if the WiFi connection goes through the PC (repeater in front, dongle in the back), the WiFi connection may be unreliable for this reason too.

Adding a small extension cable will give some distance between the PC and the dongle. That helps in both cases.